# Metadata on scientific articles (economics) conditional to set of queries

Tags: data-request, api, research, metadata, bibliometrics

I am looking for an API/software (free or open source) able to download metadata on scientific articles (economics) according to a set of queries (e.g., words in the title/abstract, keywords, JEL code, year of publication, and journal).

This has to be seen in the perspective of a systematic literature review.

The IDEAS/Repc (multisource) database contains the information I am looking for, however, I do not get how to systematically download the data.

Answer (score 1):

[You can request an API key](https://ideas.repec.org/api.html) from RePEc. The above link discusses API format and another API for citations.

Answer (score 0):

*(just for the diversity of ideas)*

You can download from the [econ](https://arxiv.org/archive/econ) section of arxiv.org with several options for bulk data access:

https://arxiv.org/help/bulk_data

For example, via the API, with specific queries

https://arxiv.org/help/api

Or bulk download, and then filter down the results. This bulk method could be of interest because you can build a vocabulary of interesting terms, based on your original list, but iteratively adding non-stop-words that often appear with your original list.

https://arxiv.org/help/bulk_data_s3